# iOS check nil value in iCloud storage

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to check if a NSDate in the iCloud KeyValueStore is nil, but I'm encountering a bug :

```
if let expirationDate: NSDate = NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.defaultStore().valueForKey(StorageManager.SUBSCRIPTION_EXPIRATION_DATE) as? NSDate {
        print(expirationDate)
}
```

`[<NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore 0x7fe03e0088f0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key subscriptionexpirationdate.'`

I tried a lot of solution on internet to check if a NSDate is nil, but it doesn't work. The error seems to be linked with IBOutlet in storyboard (I read that) but when I comment the code, it's working great.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

I replaced the valueForKey method with objectForKey in the condition, and it works.